# Access properties in ViewModel in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I have a viewmodel class with two properties (Both of them objects of other classes). I am able to access the variables from the parent class using

```
 @Model.Parent.ParentProperty1
```

But I am not able to access the variables in the child class with the statement

```
 @Model.Child.Property1
```

My ViewModel (Excerpt)

```
 public virtual Parent parent {get;set}
 public virtual IEnumerable<Child> Children {get;set;}
```

Child class has a reference to the parent class in its definition.

What i am trying to achieve

I want to access the parent property from the child class. Something like

```
 @Model.Child.ParentProperty1
        or
 @Model.Child.Property1
```

When i try to access the properties the intelisense suggests me functions that could be applied on IEnumerable.

Is there a way through which i can access the property values?

PS : I am trying to access the variable sin my View.

Comment: Your model does not have a property named `Child`. It does have one named `Children` which is `IEnumerable<Child>` so assuming it contains at least one element it would be `@Model.Children[0].SomeProperty` or `@foreach (var child in Model,Children) { @child.SomeProperty }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: thanks for your comment:):).. I should be accessing the properties with the variable name of `IEnumerable`. I usually give the same name to avoid confusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well intellisense is correct. You're trying to an access `IEnumerable`. You can access specific elements from an `IEnumerable` using the [`ElementAt`-function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb299233(v=vs.100).aspx). Here is an example for the first element:

```
@Model.Children.ElementAt(0)
```

My guess is that you want to loop over your child-elements? You can do that by using a [`foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ttw7t8t6(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
@foreach(var child in Model.Children)
{
    var parent = child.Parent;
}
```